# Web application using dash

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, web-applications, containers, plotly-dash

How to expand the width of a container to accomadate more number of plots in a single row?
I could only create columns upto 12 using a bootstrap dash components. Any solution?

Comment: Could you please provide what have you tried so far?

Comment: import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
df = pd.read_csv('https://git.io/fjpo3', usecols=['name', 'group', 'year', 'value'])
df.head(3)
fig = px.bar(df,
             x ="name",
             y ="value",
             color ='group',
             animation_frame ='year',
             hover_name ='name')
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus") # optional, drop animation buttons
fig.show()

Comment: row1 = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig)),dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig)),dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig)),dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(figure=fig))]))
                html.Br(),
            ]),
    ]
)
def run_server(self,
               port=8087,
               debug=True,
               threaded=True,
               **flask_run_options):
    self.server.run(port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)

Comment: app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.GRID])
app.title="Some Dashboard"


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
   "Dashboard using Dash"],
    style={
    'fontFamily': 'sans-serif',
    'textAlign': 'center',
    'fontSize':'2rem',
    'color':'white',
    'backgroundColor':' #696969',
    },),

    html.Div(row1),
    html.Br(),
    ],

    style={
    'color':'black',
    'backgroundColor':'#2F4F4F ',
     'overflowY': 'scroll'
    },
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=8087)

Comment: This is my code. Let me know if you have any ideas to achieve plotting no of visuals in a single row in dash

Answer (score 0):

You could put multiple plots into one div.
I assume right now you have a div with 12 plots each representing a cell in bootstrap view.

```
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(plot0, width=1)
    ... 
])
```

You could nest grouping them further to achieve that.

```
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(dbc.Row([dbc.Col(plot0), dbc.Col(plot1)])),
    dbc.Col(dbc.Row([dbc.Col(plot2), dbc.Col(plot3)]))
    ...
])
```

[You might find nested docs on grid system of original Boostrap useful](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting)

Comment: we can, but we will not get a clear visuals/plots by doing that, because when you nest the columns, however the plots size will be reduced more, it will not be useful. If we can expand the container size we can accomodate no of columns. But using the dbc, its restricted to plot upto only 12 columns.

Comment: Isn't your container maximum at screen size anyway? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. At one hand you say you want more than 12 plots/row but given you can, there is a problem with the size of the plots.